# How to get column names as part of withColumn statement according to some condition in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with dummy encoded values like so:

```
    user    domain1      domain2     domain3..........  conversions

    abcd    1            0           0                   1
    gcxe    0            1           2                   0
    .       .            .           .                   .
    .       .            .           .                   .
    .       .            .           .                   .
    .       .            .           .                   .
```

What I want to do is create a column 'vw_format' with each row of 'vw_format' containing a string which contains the column names that are not 0 in that row.
So i want a column like so:

```
    'vw_format'

    '1|d domain1'
    '0|d domain1 domain3'
         .
         .
         .
```

How do i do this? I cannot use collect() because i have a large dataset.

The "1|" and the "0|" just represent the conversions column which i have implemented already.

I tried to do it this way but it did not work:

```
df = df.withColumn("conversions",F.when(col('conversions') == 1, '1 10 | ').otherwise("-1 | "))

line = []
def myfunc(x):

    line = ""+x+""
    return line

df = df.withColumn('vw_format', sf.concat(sf.col('conversions'),sf.lit('d '), sf.lit(when(sf.col([i for i in list])!=1,myfunc(i)))))
```

I've done this in python before using iterrows() but I can't in pyspark. 
Note:- This is a large dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) and [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) to accomplish this.

First create a list of column names for the "domain" columns. You'd have to adjust this to meet your needs, but based on what you've provided in the question the following may work:

```python
domains = [c for c in df.columns if c.lower().startswith("domain")]
print(domains)
#['domain1', 'domain2', 'domain3']
```

Now concatenate the `conversions` column and the literal string `"d"` with a `"|"` as a separator. Next concatenate this result with each of the columns in `domains` that have a non-zero value with a space as a separator.

We exploit the fact that `when` returns `null` by default if the condition is not met and no `otherwise` is specified. (Concatenating will skip the `null`s.)

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, lit, when

df.withColumn(
    "vw_format", 
    concat_ws(
        " ", 
        concat_ws("|", "conversions", lit("d")), 
        *[when(col(c) != 0, lit(c)) for c in domains]
    )
).show(truncate=False)
#+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-------------------+
#|user|domain1|domain2|domain3|conversions|vw_format          |
#+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-------------------+
#|abcd|1      |0      |0      |1          |1|d domain1        |
#|gcxe|0      |1      |2      |0          |0|d domain2 domain3|
#+----+-------+-------+-------+-----------+-------------------+
```